# The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive in c# (windows forms)

Tags: c#

I used the third party APIs to send SMS and while executing the code I'm getting the error at this line code :

```
 HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();
```

The error is : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive

I did R&D on this error and I get this code (to write in App.Config) but it is also not working fine

```
<system.net>
    <settings>
        <httpwebrequest useunsafeheaderparsing="true" />
    </settings>
</system.net>
```

C# Code :

```
public static string SendSMS(string MobileNumber, string Message)  
{  
  
    //Your authentication key  
    string authKey = "";  
       
    //Multiple mobiles numbers separated by comma  
    string mobileNumber = MobileNumber;  
    //Sender ID,While using route4 sender id should be 6 characters long.  
    string senderId = "TESTIN";  
    //Your message to send, Add URL encoding here.  
       
    string message = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Message);  
    string route = "4";  
    //Prepare you post parameters  
    StringBuilder sbPostData = new StringBuilder();  
    sbPostData.AppendFormat("authkey={0}", authKey);  
    sbPostData.AppendFormat("&mobiles={0}", mobileNumber);  
    sbPostData.AppendFormat("&message={0}", message);  
    sbPostData.AppendFormat("&sender={0}", senderId);  
    sbPostData.AppendFormat("&route={0}", route);  
  
  
    //Call Send SMS API  
    string sendSMSUri = "https://control.msg91.com/api/sendhttp.php";  
    //Create HTTPWebrequest  
    HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sendSMSUri);  
    //Prepare and Add URL Encoded data  
    UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();  
    byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(sbPostData.ToString());  
    //Specify post method  
    httpWReq.Method = "POST";  
    httpWReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";  
    httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;  
    using (Stream stream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream())  
    {  
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);  
    }  
    //Get the response  
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();  
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());  
    string responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();  
  
    //Close the response  
    reader.Close();  
  
    response.Close();  
    return responseString;  
  
}
```

I'm not sure where I did the mistake

Give me the suggestion. How can I achieve this ?

I'm new to this kind of third party APIs logic implementation.

Comment: The server is closing the connection, probably because of a firewall or because of invalid URL. Side note: `response` and `reader` should be in `using` blocks

Comment: @Charlieface, Thnx for your reply 
I used the using statement Ex :  `using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse())
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    reader.Close();
                    response.Close();

                    return responseString;
                }`
but still I'm getting the same error !!!.

Any better solution !